# How to get DFA intersection?

Tags: intersection, computation-theory, dfa

How do we combine two dfa using intersection method ?

Comment: Is this homework?  Otherwise, I am not familiar with the exact procedure spelled out in books, but I'm betting I could come up with a program to combine two DFAs that ran in time O(state transitions).

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732815/calculate-if-two-infinite-regex-solution-sets-dont-intersect) who's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7732923/188044) will probably work for this question.

Comment: Specifically, the part after the EDIT: spells out how to make a DFA accepting L1 intersect L2, given DFAs accepting L1 and L2.

Answer (score 2):

Use the cross product construction, explained formally [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/gbooks/toc.pdf).

Essentially you cross product the sets of states in each one to get a list of meta states corresponding to any combination of states for each machine. This allows you to do a parallel evaluation to accept if both accept.